# TypeError: takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, tkinter, typeerror

I'm new to programming, learnt python syntax. Stuck at my first GUI program!

Here is my code:

```
#User name

userLabel = Label(self.signView, text="User Name")
userLabel.grid(sticky = E)
self.userEntry = Entry(self.signView)
self.userEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)

self.labelUserVar = StringVar()
self.validLabel = Label(self.signView, textvariable=self.labelUserVar, 
                         anchor="w", fg="red")
self.validLabel.grid(row=0, column=2)
self.userEntry.bind("<Return>", self.CheckUser)
```

Here's the following CheckUser() function:

```
def CheckUser(self):
    self.labelUserVar.set("unavailable user name!")
```

I got this error.

```
TypeError: CheckUser() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: Just so you understand (if you don't already), the error comes due to the function requiring 1 argument (self), but you are giving it 2, self and its an event, due to the binding to the enter key. Thought I'd explain it as I didn't think the answer given was clear as for why it fixes the error. cheers!

Answer (score 9):

The function you pass to `.bind()` [takes the event as an argument](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#bindings-and-events), and it will be passed in regardless of whether you need it.

Change the function definition to

```
def CheckUser(self, event):
    self.labelUserVar.set("unavailable user name!")
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

`server.bind((host,port))`

Not this:

`server.bind(host,port)`

Bind the address (host, port) to the socket. Under AF_INET, the address is expressed in the form of a tuple (host, port).